# How to pass an increment from child component to a counter in parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

To get some context, I've built a regular Counter App in Angular before. But, to get some more experience in Angular I'm trying to build each increment/decrement button as its owns component to update the Count in the Parent component. I can get the increment to work in my child component, but I'm unsure of how to pass the updated Increment back up to the parent. Thank you.

**Here is my ts file in the Parent file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'complicatedAngularCounter';

  currentCount:any = 0;
}
```

**Here is my html code in the Parent**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Count: {{currentCount}}</p>
<app-plus [count]="currentCount" ></app-plus>
```

**Here is my ts code in the Child Increment file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plus',
  templateUrl: './plus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plus.component.css']
})
export class PlusComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() count:any;
  @Output() countUpdatePlus = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onPlus() {
    this.count ++

  }
}
```

**Here is the html code in the Child Increment**

```
<button (click)="onPlus()">++</button>
<h1>Here is {{count}}</h1>
```

Comment: You should look into the Output decorator, and EventEmitter.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need some changes in your child component, `Angular` uses `Typescript`, so, I encourage you to explicitly define your properties:

```js
 @Input() count: number; // instead of count: any
 @Output() countUpdatePlus = new EventEmitter<number>(); // instead of <string>
```

Avoid using `any`, you lose the purpose of `Typescript` if you start defining `any` to every property, variable, etc..., you ended up having plain javascript.

You can read more about it here [TypeScript: Stop Using 'any', There's a Type For That](http://TypeScript:%20Stop%20Using%20%27any%27,%20There%27s%20a%20Type%20For%20That)

Since you have your `countUpdatePlus` event emitter, you are missing this logic in your `onPlus()`:

```js
onPlus() {
 this.count++;
 this.countUpdatePlus.emit(this.count); // will emit your updated count property
}
```

Then, in your parent component, you should catch that emitted value:

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Count: {{currentCount}}</p>
<app-plus 
  [count]="currentCount" 
  (countUpdatePlus)="onUpdatedCounter($event)">
</app-plus>
```

Parent ts file:

```js
...
onUpdatedCounter(value: number): void {
  // do something with your updated counter 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn’t this: this.countUpdatePlus.next(this.count) be this.countUpdatePlus.emit(this.count)?

Comment: @MikeOne, both `next` and `emit` works for emitting, I have tested them, although, I see `emit` is commonly used, I changed my answer using `emit`

Comment: `EventEmitter` from `@angular/core` has both, `next` and `emit`, like I said, both works as intented, but, I am not sure when to use each of them.

Comment: Never knew that, thanks!